# Page Content and Top Navigation completely disappear when installing any extension in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having an issue where my top nav (I use pronav) and all the contents of .col-main on every page completely disappear when installing any extension. Even when I uninstall the extension and completely remove the files, the problem still persists and I have to restore a backup.

On installation I disable Compilation and flush the cache when installation is complete but I still have no luck.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated?

Comment: which extension you used

Comment: I tried installing both Amasty Duplicate Categories and also Olark Live Chat. The exact same issue happens with both extensions.

Comment: What modules and themes do you have installed already, and which was the last successful module installed without this happening? You mention at least one other module being installed, ProNav - so unless you have others added after that - it's quite likely that it's that one causing problems. Try removing it anything else newly added and then try again with the ones that failed.